# Navigation addListener does not executes after await action

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am listening to focus event on navigation in React native & using `@react-navigation^5.x.x`
in `componentDidMount`. If only this action is written, then it works well and executes the code within it.

But in my case, I am fetching data from API (Also tried by mocking await) and using await before adding focus listener.
It's not getting listened to for the first time. But when I go to another page and comes back, It starts working/executing.

Here's my code snippet.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // 3 sec

    navigation.addListener('focus', async (data) => {
        console.log('This block not works for first time when I come on page.')
    })

}
```

Edit - Even If I remove await and put the whole block in timeout, then also it stops executing the focus callback.

Comment: It's not just any callback, it's an event listener. You listen to "focus" event, it calls your listener when the event is fired. If you wait/delay adding the listener to the time where "focus" event has already fired, your listener isn't going to get called.

Comment: Ohh, it seems to be. But I need to use some data when the focus event gets fired. And I am getting that data from API. How Should I do this so that it fires and also I can use the data from API ?

Comment: It cannot wait to fire **after** you fetch the data from API, events don't work that way. Why do you need it to fire after your data is fetched? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `async` on the life cycle try this instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const getData = async (params) => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // 3 sec

        navigation.addListener('focus', async (data) => {
            console.log('This block not works for first time when I come on page.')
        })

    }
    getData()
}
```

Comment: or you can use `.then` method

Comment: I tried both methods, Don't know why it stops listening focus effect of react navigation.

Comment: maybe because navigation.addListener() return an unsub function, did you try it with useEffect hook?, also there is a react hook called useFocusEffect

Comment: Any idea on how I can fix my issue ?